# Syntax issue involving a ".replace" function

Tags: javascript

So I have a Google sheet that collects registration data from customers.  Included in the data collected is a student's name, the session the student elected to attend and a credit card number.  Once a submission has been made, I get a notification.  Upon notification, I go to my Google sheet and charge the credit card the appropriate amount.

Once the credit card has been charged, I then want to generate a confirmation email to the customer that includes the student's name, the session the student registered to attend and the amount charged to the credit card.  My code seems to work fine except when it comes to replacing curly bracket placeholders in my "template text" (i.e., {Name},{sessions} and {ChargeAmount} with the actual values which I've defined as variables.

```
Note:  When I just replace {StudentName} with text like "Joe" it works.  However, {Sessions} does not get replaced and neither does {ChargeAmount}.  I think this is a syntax error.
```

Here's what I really want to happen but can't get to work:

var emailText = templateText.replace("{Name}",studentName);templateText.replace("{Sessions}",sessionName);templateText.replace("{ChargeAmount}",ChgAmt);

```
function SendEmail() {
 // Fetch the email address

var emailRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1").getRange("B2");
var studentRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1").getRange("C2");
var studentName = studentRange.getValues();
var sessionRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1").getRange("D2");
var sessionName = sessionRange.getValues();
var emailAddress = emailRange.getValues();
var ChgAmt = Browser.inputBox("Charge Amount");
var templateText = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Template").getRange(1,1).getValue();

  // NOTE!  What I really want to do is replace {Name} with the var "studentName"... not the text "Joe", {Sessions} with the var "sessionName" and {ChargeAmount} with the var "ChgAmt". I can't this to work either!  STRUGGLING!!!

var emailText = templateText.replace("{StudentName}","Joe");templateText.replace("{Sessions}","May - Session#1");templateText.replace("{ChargeAmount}","$500");

// Send Alert Email.
var subject = 'Junior Golf Clinic Registration Receipt';
var message = emailText;

MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message); 


}
```

Here's the result of my existing code which does not properly pull in the values I need.

```
useremail@gmail.com
9:18 AM (37 minutes ago)
to me

This is the email body.

This is the amount charged to credit card {ChargeAmount}.  [Not right.  This should be the actual value represented by the var "ChgAmt"]

This is the student's name: Joe  [this seems to work when I replace the placeholder {Name} with text like "Joe" but not when I try to replace the placeholder {Name} with the var "studentName"]

These are the sessions the student is scheduled to attend: {Sessions}  
[Not right.  This should be the actual sessions represented by the var "sessionName"]

Here's more information about the clinics themselves.
```

Answer (score 2):

This line is incorrect, you're never actually storing your other replace statements.

`var emailText = templateText.replace("{StudentName}","Joe");templateText.replace("{Sessions}","May - Session#1");templateText.replace("{ChargeAmount}","$500");`

It should be:

`var emailText = templateText.replace("{StudentName}","Joe").replace("{Sessions}","May - Session#1").replace("{ChargeAmount}","$500");`

Answer (score 0):

As jmcgriz notes, the problem is with the separate calls to `.replace`.  Chaining them fixes your issue.

Here is some dummy code showing what that might look like:

```js
function SendEmail() {
  // fetch these values as you need
  var studentName = 'Joe'
  var sessionName = "May - Session#1";
  var emailAddress = 'joe@joe.com'
  var chargeAmt = "$500";

  // This is what needed to change
  var emailText = templateText
     .replace("{StudentName}", studentName)
     .replace("{Sessions}", sessionName)
     .replace("{ChargeAmount}", chargeAmt);

  var subject = 'Junior Golf Clinic Registration Receipt';
  var message = emailText;

  MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message); 
}

SendEmail()
```

```html
<script>
// Mocking MailApp for testing

const MailApp = {
  sendEmail: (addr, subj, mess) => 
    console.log(`Sending "${addr}" email "${subj}"\n\n${mess}`)
}

const templateText = `
This is the email body.

This is the amount charged to credit card {ChargeAmount}.

This is the student's name: {StudentName}

These are the sessions the student is scheduled to attend: {Sessions}  

Here's more information about the clinics themselves.`


</script>
```

Comment: Ok.  I'm just about to give up on this.  I have been working on this for hours and cannot for the life of me get this procedure to work.   Here is the detail report I get when I try to run the code:  "TYPE ERROR:  Cannot find function replace in Object This is the email body.  This is the amount charged to the credit card:  {Cost}.  Is there a way I can expose this project to someone so they can look at my actual code and tell me whet the heck I'm doing wrong?

Comment: That error means most likely means that the template you are trying to get from the document is not a String, but an Object.  Here is a list of some code-sharing sites: https://www.sitepoint.com/7-code-playgrounds/.  But I don't know if any of them have any way to integrate with Google Docs.